# Passing value to target webpage using phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am using Phantomjs. I need to pass certain information to the webpage (`http://localhost:4569/index.html`) we are targeting. The idea is, as soon as the target page loads, pass a JSON object to page & set it a globally accessible variable. Something like `window.data  = {....}`. Once this variable is set, the target page will make use of this variable. Is it possible to get the desired result using Phantomjs?

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
var settings = {
  operation: "POST",
  encoding: "utf8",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  data: JSON.stringify({
    some: "data",
    another: ["custom", "data"]
  })
};

page.open('http://localhost:4569/index.html', settings, function(status) {
  console.log('Status: ' + status);
  //
```

Comment: How is the data being used? When does the page JS run in order to use the injected data? Does it run during load, after page load or even at a later time?

Answer (score 1):

One way that you might be able to facilitate this is a combination of [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval()) and [`injectJs()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/inject-js.html).  I would check for the data in the target page every few seconds.  Then I would inject in a piece of data using `injectJs`.  Then I would digest the injected data and have the phantomjs script react accordingly.

## index.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Phantest</title>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Phantom Test</h1>
        <p>Test of phantom</p>
    </main>
    <script>
        (function () {
            console.log("Hello");
            setInterval(function () {
                if (window.myVar) {
                    console.log("window.myVar is here!");
                    console.log(window.myVar);
                }
            }, 1000);
        }());
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

## phan.js

```
/*jslint node:true*/

"use strict";

var page = require("webpage").create();

page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};

page.open("http://127.0.0.1:52987/index.html", function (status) {
    if (status === "success") {
        page.injectJs("inject.js");
    }
});
```

## inject.js

```
/*jslint browser:true devel:true*/
console.log("I'm from Phantom");

window.myVar = "I'm myVar!";
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Looks like using `injectJS`, I can include an external file. Is there any way to pass  a javascript object instead of injecting a file? When user executes Phantomjs command, he will also pass a Javascript object which i need to inject to the target site. Voting up for the help.

Comment: @OpenStack Maybe take a look at how [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21472068/691711) puts data into the page instead.  That way you don't have to keep a separate file.